# Show multiple divs

Tags: javascript, php, jquery, html, codeigniter

so, I'm working on a project that has 2 tables in database that are related!

I need via JavaScript Hide and Show the divs containing the right information.

I got a main product **Stone**, and each **Stone** has 2 other **Stone Types**

So if I click on the img that has **Stone1**, I want to show **Stone1.1**, **Stone1.2**, **etc** and hide all the other **StoneTypes**.

This is what I got now on JS

```
jQuery('.Pedras').click(function(){
          jQuery('.SubPedras').hide();
          jQuery('#div'+$(this).attr('target')).show();
    });
```

The problem here is that I only get the first div to show, eventhough I have 2 divs with the same *Name* example:

```
<div id="div{IdPedra}" class="SubPedras">
<div id="div{IdPedra}" class="SubPedras">
<div id="div{IdPedra}" class="SubPedras">
```

And {IdPedra} Is the id of the stone in the database, so I will get "div1" two or 3 times, etc.

Can anyone pls help me, I'm not able to find a suitable solution for my need.

Thank you!

Comment: _... the same **Name**_? That's look like multiple divs with the same ID to me

Comment: ID's should be unique. The first element with that ID will always be the one called.

Comment: @AlonEitan Yes, have some trouble on explaining! But that's it, it is the same Id.

Comment: @JerdineSabio, Yeah, thats why it only calls the first div, what should be my aproach?

Comment: Add another class that represents the parent. Show based on that class.

Comment: @GabrielGomes But you can't do it, that is considered as invalid HTML as JerdineSabio explained

Comment: @PatrickQ I'm not really getting the way of doing it, I'm just all over the place, and I'm probably missing the easyiest thing...

Comment: Instead of `id="div{IdPedra}"` you can do something like `data-id="div{IdPedra}"` and then select them using `jQuery('div[data-id="div' + $(this).attr('target') + '"]').show();` - I'm not sure how your html is structured so I just hope that will work

Answer (score 0):

You could use data-attributes to accomplish this. In your change my code to;

```
<div data-id="{IdPedra}" class="SubPedras">Stone 1.1</div>
<div data-id="{IdPedra}" class="SubPedras">Stone 1.2</div>
<div data-id="{IdPedra}" class="SubPedras">Stone 2.1</div>
<div data-id="{IdPedra}" class="SubPedras">Stone 2.2</div>
```

You can access an element's data-attribute by using $(element).data("name"); this is equivalent to data-name. I also stored the Pedras

Loop through the SubPedras and check if they match the button where the parent category or value you wish to use as filter. Run the snippet, thanks!

(You could also store them to class attribute instead of data)

```js
jQuery('.Pedras').click(function() {
  // store button value to variable
  var pedraValue = $(this).val();
  
  // loop through the SubPedras
  $(".SubPedras").each(function() {
    
    // get the value from data attribute
    if ($(this).data("id") == pedraValue) {
      
      // if match show
      $(this).show();
    }
    else{
      // else hide
      $(this).hide();
    }
  });
});
```

```css
.SubPedras{
  line-height:40px;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div data-id="Stone1" class="SubPedras">Stone 1.1</div>
<div data-id="Stone1" class="SubPedras">Stone 1.2</div>
<div data-id="Stone2" class="SubPedras">Stone 2.1</div>
<div data-id="Stone2" class="SubPedras">Stone 2.2</div>

<button class="Pedras" value="Stone1">Stone 1</button>
<button class="Pedras" value="Stone2">Stone 2</button>
```

Comment: So it is trigerring, but it is always hiding everything... And that's because my PedraValue is always returning null.

Comment: Nevermind! I just put it to work, instead of getting the value of the button, I just get the Id, because the button Id will never repeat! Thanks mate!